# index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5, how to solve it?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, pandapower

I am a beginner in python and trying to write a code to determine the admittance matrix. my admittance list is defined as Y_ges

```
Y_ges = [ 9.89583333-40.47448077j  27.9209622 -10.73883162j
         27.9209622 -10.73883162j  27.9209622 -10.73883162j
         27.9209622 -10.73883162j]
```

At the beginning i created a zero matrix and determined its size.

`a=np.zeros((len(net.bus),len(net.bus)),dtype=complex)`

then i created a function to fill the matrix row by row

```
def fillmatrix(n):
    for i in range(len(n)):
        #print(i)
        if i == 0 :
            zerolist=[0]*len(net.bus)
            print("we are in if loop",i)
            zerolist[i]=Y_ges[i]
            zerolist[i+1]=-Y_ges[i]
            a[i]=zerolist
            #print(zerolist)
            #print(a)
        else:
            print("we are in else loop",i)
            zerolist=[0]*len(net.bus)
            zerolist[i-1]=-Y_ges[i-1]
            zerolist[i]=Y_ges[i-1]+Y_ges[i+1]
            zerolist[i+1]=-Y_ges[i+1]
            a[i]=zerolist
            i+=1
            print(a)
            print("i =",i)
            #print(zerolist)
     
            

fillmatrix(Y_ges)
```

i expect this matrix

```
[[  9.89583333-40.47448077j  -9.89583333+40.47448077j
    0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j
    0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j        ]
 [ -9.89583333+40.47448077j  37.81679553-51.21331239j
  -27.9209622 +10.73883162j   0.         +0.j
    0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j        ]
 [  0.         +0.j         -27.9209622 +10.73883162j
   55.8419244 -21.47766323j -27.9209622 +10.73883162j
    0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j        ]
 [  0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j
  -27.9209622 +10.73883162j  55.8419244 -21.47766323j
  -27.9209622 +10.73883162j   0.         +0.j        ]
 [  0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j
    0.         +0.j         -27.9209622 +10.73883162j
  55.8419244 -21.47766323j  -27.9209622 +10.73883162j]
 [  0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j
    0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j
 -27.9209622 +10.73883162j  27.9209622 +10.73883162j]]
```

but i get this matrix

```
[[  9.89583333-40.47448077j  -9.89583333+40.47448077j
    0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j
    0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j        ]
 [ -9.89583333+40.47448077j  37.81679553-51.21331239j
  -27.9209622 +10.73883162j   0.         +0.j
    0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j        ]
 [  0.         +0.j         -27.9209622 +10.73883162j
   55.8419244 -21.47766323j -27.9209622 +10.73883162j
    0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j        ]
 [  0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j
  -27.9209622 +10.73883162j  55.8419244 -21.47766323j
  -27.9209622 +10.73883162j   0.         +0.j        ]
 [  0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j
    0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j
    0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j        ]
 [  0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j
    0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j
    0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j        ]]
```

and this error message:

```
 File "/Users/pythonuser/Desktop/Probe code ", line 230, in <module>
   fillmatrix(Y_ges)

 File "/Users/pythonuser/Desktop/Probe code ", line 220, in fillmatrix
   zerolist[i]=Y_ges[i-1]+Y_ges[i+1]

IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5
```

any idea ?

Comment: You get the range and use it to loop but for the last item in this range/loop `[i+1]` is going to to be out of bounds.

Comment: how can I solve the problem? is there any method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy arrays are zero indexed. It starts at index zero and ends with the last element at index len-1. You shouldn't modify i in the loop.

I have read your code and understood that you want a somewhat diagonal matrix, so here goes the code:

```py
def fillmatrix(n):
    zeros = np.zeros((len(n)+1, len(n)+3), dtype=n.dtype)
    p = np.pad(n, 1) # padding simplifies the logic, no ifs
    for i in range(len(n)+1):
       zeros[i, i:i+3] = [-p[i], p[i]+p[i+1], -p[i+1]]
    return zeros[:, 1:-1]
```

Comment: Sorry, I messed up with the indexes in the first answer, corrected now.

Comment: Hello Gabriel, thx for your help, the n list have a 5 elements so i get after your code a matrix with the shape (5,5), but i need a matrix with the shape (6,6) as I showed above.

Comment: So I didn't think I understood correctly. Where would get the 6th element from? It if just copying the last element? Why does your Y_ges matrix have 5 elements, not 6? Why are the elements from the second position all equals to 27.9209622 -10.73883162j? Couldn't you just make Y_ges an array of size 6?

Comment: so i have a network with 6 nodes, therefore a matrix 6,6 and 5 connecting lines
Y_ges matrix is ​​the values ​​of the lines. The first line value connects nodes 1 with 2
therefore [  9.89583333-40.47448077j     -9.89583333+40.47448077j   0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j   0.         +0.j    0.         +0.j        ]. node number 2 has a connection to node 1 and 3, therefore [ -9.89583333+40.47448077j    
        37.81679553-51.21331239j
  -27.9209622 +10.73883162j   0.         +0.j  0.         +0.j     0.         +0.j ].

Comment: node number 3 therefore has a connection with node 2 and 4, therefore  [  0.       +0.j         -27.9209622 +10.73883162j   55.8419244 -21.47766323j -27.9209622 +10.73883162j 0.         +0.j      0.         +0.j  ].   the last node, i.e. node 6, is only connected to node number 5, so I had to get the last row like this, [  0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j  0.         +0.j           0.         +0.j          -27.9209622 +10.73883162j  27.9209622 +10.73883162j]

Comment: Ok, I changed the code accordingly, it should work as you expect now